# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file with React and Babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My code was working perfectly an hour ago but suddenly showed the error below. I do not recall making any specific changes. 
 ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    | import App from './components/App';
    |

> ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('app'));
>       ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.'

My webpack config file is webpack.config.js and is as

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node-modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader' 
            },
            {
            test:/\.(s*)css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']

            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'url-loader',
                },
              },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template:'./src/index.html'
            }),
            // new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            //          filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            //       chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
            //         })
    ]
}
```

App.js is as

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="">
                <h1>Checkk</h1>
                   </div>     
        )
    }
}

export default  App;
```

and my index.js is as

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Please help!1

Comment: Is app a JS or JSX file?

Comment: are you having <div id="app"></div> in your index.html?